# Mysql session variable not incrementing

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i'm trying to write a mysql query in leetcode for finding the top 3 values in multiple groups. for that i wrote the below sql.

@current_dep session variable is working fine. but when it comes to @dep_rank it's not increasing, it's showing 1 for all records. is there something i'm doing wrong?

`select @dep_rank := if(@current_dep=department.name,@dep_rank+1,1) as dep_rank, @current_dep:=department.name  from employee , department  where employee.departmentid=department.id order by department.name`

Comment: does @current_dep same with department.name?

Comment: @current_dep must not be = to department.name for the counter to add